# Steel percussion mallets

Tags: percussion, mallet-percussion

I'm going to be striking a variety of unconventional bells varying in material from steel to brass, bronze and aluminium. I wonder if there is anything against using precision mallets with stainless steel heads rather than the more common aluminium, brass or even plastic and wood varieties? Would it be best to use steel only on those bells that I know are of solid steel construction?

Comment: What end product is in mind? A concert, destruction of bells, etc?

Comment: Hah, no I'm hoping the bells will be intact afterwards! It will be for concerts/performance, but light playing / smaller venues, and mic'ed up if larger venues.

Comment: I should add, one concern is whether the sonic characteristics would be radically different with steel compared to brass heads.

Comment: "sonic characteristics" - if I pick my guitar with the meat of my thumb, I get a different tone than if I pick it with a metal pick.  Some might describe the difference as degrees of "mellow".  I suspect a steel vs a wooden mallet will have a similar impact (pun intended) on your bells.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many variables with mallet percussion:

- the (in this case) bells themselves
- the mallets: material, size, shape, weight
- the impact: position, angle, force, phase

In your comment, you seem to be concerned with both the potential for damage and the sound quality.

Steel (or other metal) heads will have the *potential* for scratching or otherwise damaging the bells.  Steel is certainly harder than brass, which makes its potential for causing damage greater.  Whether or not damaging occurs will mainly be determined by the impact.

Different mallet material will certainly affect the sound, and whether these changes are acceptable/desirable is really something you (or the percussionist) will have to determine with experience and experimentation.